# FMCW RADAR using Phased Array Antenna

Tags: music, usrp

I need assistance to calculate angle of arrival using MUSIC algorithm for Phased Antenna Array with GNU radio and USRP
#Zeeshan

Comment: hi! Welcome here. That's nice, but this is a Question & Answer platform, aimed at answering precise questions. You haven't asked a question! So, we can't answer something. Also, you haven't described your scenario including used hardware, software, number of antennas, … at all!